# Telnet host 25 - no route to host

Tags: email, centos, cpanel, exim

I have basic VM (xenserver installed on dedicated machine) with cPanel on CentOs 6.8, exim 4.87 - nothing fancy. For 2 weeks I am having issue with sending e-mails - it is not global, affects about 10% outgoing emails, random domains, as it is online store. cPanel says "no route to host". I took one of them and did tests:

ping mail.host.com - that works good (so it is not dns issue)

telnet mail.host.com 25 - resolves ip address but shows 'no route to host'

I tried telnet from XenServer (host of that VM) and it works good so it is not any ISP or ovh firewall. Something blocks that in my VM.

I've tried "service iptables stop" and also completely disabled csf and lfd in cPanel - nothing helped.

Do you have any idea what else could I check? I struggle with that for a week and I stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP/IHS are used to restrict port 25 routing unless you explicitly configure it. You may also check this.

On the other hand, you may also check the way your VM is getting its network access.